# Google Forms: Answers beside the question instead of below

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to have the answers beside the questions instead of below them in Google Forms?
Below a picture with a [very simple] explanation

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx5lV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of change is not supported by Google Form.

You may need to create a web form yourself.